# Autolayout Imagesize should increase as per UItextview Text

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uitextview, ios-autolayout

I a using `Autolayout` to implement in iPAD and want to perform task like as per my Textview text the Image set behind set as per Text. Like this:

[image]

But could not set proper constraint for it.

Can anyone suggest what to do for it to make it perfect ?

Comment: Are you using textview inside tableviewcell?

Comment: Which constraints you have given to image related to textview?

Comment: No, I am using Textview in Scrollview @Irfan and set only width constraint of textview at present.

Comment: Add exactly same constraints to imageview as textview. Then when the textview grow imageview will also.

Comment: @Irfan but how UIImageview identifies the textview text size without any relation. Still ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set as following :

[image]

If It'll not work then remove and add another TextView and set as i suggest.
 
I think, It'll helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can set equal height constraints for the Imageview and Textview.
For textview, you can set the background image rather than keeping a separate imageview behind the textview. Then the image will be resized as the textview size changes.